# splitting a group by preferences

Tags: c#, algorithm, grouping

I'm trying to take a group of twenty people (labeled `1 - 20`) and spilt them into five subgroups of 4 each based upon expressed preferences of who those people wish to be with.

Each person in the group of 20 could express 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 preferences.  For example, `person1` could select 0 (no preference of  who they are with),  or 14 (in a group with `person14`) or could express to be in a group with persons 14, 20, 6, and 7.  Ideally each person with a preference would be in a group with at least one choice.

Ideas on an algorithm?

Comment: Is it a homework, what have you tried, what is the exact criteria, ie. if you will connect person one with 14,20 in the same group, will it be better solution, than just grouping this person with 14?

Comment: So, your friend has asked for help, and you're asking for help from us to help your friend because you can't help him?! Ask your friend to come over to StackOverflow.com and ask for Jon Skeet!

Comment: 1)  This isn't a homework problem.   This is a practical problem that a friend encountered in his work place and was simply looking for an application solution. He is not an applications/computer person.

2)  Other than TSQL or MS Office products, C# is what I have available so yes it has less to do with a language and more to do with the algorithm and realizing some languages are better suited for a solution than others.

Thanks for taking the time to who have responded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is not really related to C#, the algorithm is independent on the language.

A classic implementation for this problems is [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

More info:

- [Constraint satisfaction problems on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem)
- Recommended: [Chapter 5 from Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137903952)

Another approach (I would go for this): [Genetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a it too much to ask at SO, but think the problem is quite interesting, so here are some thoughts.

As *Victor Hurdugaci* says, this is mainly an algorithmic problem independent of the language (although I'd love to see my example below implemented with LINQ!)

The problem described in your question cannot yield a perfect result, i.e. it's an optimization problem (so you cannot solve it with a constraint statisfaction algorithm). You have to find an algorithm that finds the best result from the set of all possible results based on some function that indicates how good a result is (called *fitness function*).

**Naive Brute force Solution (pseudo-code)**

We start with the set of people (here: 4 to simplify things):

```
people = { a, b, c, d }
```

We can find all possible subgroups of a fixed size (here: 2) using a `choose` operator:

```
groups = people.choose(2)  // = { {a,b} {a,c} {a,d} {b,c} {b,d} {c,d} }
```

We can find all possible combinations of subgroups using the `choose` operator again:

```
combi = groups.choose(4/2) // = { {ab,ac} {ab,ad} {ab,bc} {ab,bd}
                           //     {ab,cd} {ac,ad} {ac,bc} {ac,bd}
                           //     {ac,cd} {ad,bc} {ad,bd} {ad,cd}
                           //     {bc,bd} {bc,cd} {bd,cd} }
```

Obviously people cannot be in two groups at the same time, so we remove all invalid combinations:

```
combi2 = combi.select(g => g.bigUnion().size == 4)
                           // = { {ab,cd}, {ac,bd}, {ad,bc} }
```

Now you have to find the "best" item based on some fitness function, i.e. the combination that scores best considering the preferences.

```
result = combi2.maximumBy(g => fitness(g))
```

For example, if `a` has a preference for `b`, and `b`, `c` and `d` do not have any preferences, then `calculateScore` should return a higher score for `{ab,cd}` than for `{ac,bd}` and `{ad,bc}`.

**Improved Solution**

There a several algorithms that deal with this kind of optimization problem. I think a [Hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) algorithm would suit here well.